# AngularJS - $emit fire before $on

Tags: angularjs, html

I am working with AngularJS framework. I wrote a few directives with and without their own controller and they sometimes include each other.

For every course, I use my own directive to print its informations

```
<li ng-repeat="course in courses" on-courses-loaded="fetch_subscribed">
            <course-info course="course"></course-info>
</li>
```

The 'on-courses-loaded' attribute is looking for the last element, I wrote it to do things when ng-repeat is over : a few data are prepared and signal is emitted for every function register as $rootScope.$on('courses_available', function() {}) (scope < actual scope)

```
angular.module('app').directive('onCoursesLoaded', [
    '$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                     if (scope.$last === true) 
                     {
                         element.ready(function() {
                               // Prepare things, when done return promise and then  -> 
                               $rootScope.$broadcast('courses_available');
                         });
                     }
                }
            }
        }]);
```

In course info directive, there is a call to another directive

```
<subscribe code="course.code" triggered="true"></subscribe>
```

With this code

```
<div ng-show="available">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-hide="subscribed" ng-click="subscribe()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Subscribe
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="subscribed" ng-click="unsubscribe()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Unsubscribe
    </button>
</div>
```

And THIS link function

```
if (scope.triggered === true)
{
    console.log('wait for emit');
    $rootScope.$on('courses_available', function() {
        internals.getSubscribed();
    });
}
else
{
    console.log('do not wait for emit');
    scope.$watch('code', function(value) {
        internals.getSubscribed();
    });
}
```

The biggest issue is that signal is emitted before `subscribe` directive has set its `$rootScope.$on('courses_available', ..)`

Here you can find HTML pseudo code expanded

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="course in courses | filter: search" on-courses-loaded="fetch_subscribed">
    <!--<course-info course="course"></course-info> IS NEXT DIV-->
    <div> 
        <!--<subscribe code="course.code" triggered="true"></subscribe> IS NEXT DIV-->
        <div ng-show="available">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-hide="subscribed" ng-click="subscribe()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Subscribe
            </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="subscribed" ng-click="unsubscribe()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Unsubscribe
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. I need to prepare data and emit signal after ng-repeat
2. While 1., every content from ng-repeat must subscribe to $rootScope.$on() and before emit.

If you have any tips, thank you all.

Comment: I recommend a jsFiddle or Plunker so people can see the issue as it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect finish event of ng-repeat as below

```
if (scope.$last){
      window.alert("im the last!");
}
```

I have done something like this , so I will post my code here maybe it can help you. First I created custom directive

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
      .directive('onFinishRender',['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
              $timeout(function () {
                scope.$emit('tilesCreated');
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }]);
```

Then used this directive with ng-repeat

```
   <div  on-finish-render=""   ng-repeat="tile in tiles" ></div>
```

Then I listen for this event inside another directive

```
      scope.$on('tilesCreated', function() {
         // Do something here
      });
```

P.S. Notice that in here I do all things on the same scope. But it depends on you if you want you can broadcast events on $rootScope. I just wanted to give you base idea of how to do this. I hope it will help.

Comment: Hi. I've already tried with $timeout and I use the same way as yours. The fact is that <subscribe> is not init with $on before parent directive $emit.
$on -> $emit == OK